# Catching MessageError exception from userdata.get() in Google Colaboratory secrets

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to use the userdata.get() function in Google Colab to retrieve a secret, and I want to handle the case where the secret doesn't exist. Here's my code:

```
from google.colab import userdata
try:
  userdata.get('mySecret')
except MessageError:
  print("The mySecret doesn't exists")
```

But I got this NameError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

MessageError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-7-32b2ab9e6be3> in <cell line: 2>()
      2 try:
----> 3   userdata.get('mySecret')
      4 except MessageError:

3 frames

MessageError: Error: Secret mySecret does not exist.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-7-32b2ab9e6be3> in <cell line: 2>()
      2 try:
      3   userdata.get('mySecret')
----> 4 except MessageError:
      5   print("The mySecret doesn't exists")

NameError: name 'MessageError' is not defined
```

However, I'm encountering a NameError instead of catching the MessageError. The error message suggests that the secret doesn't exist, but I'm having trouble handling it properly.

Could someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong? How can I catch the MessageError and print the desired message when the secret is not found?

I expect it caught the error which it will print:

```
The mySecret doesn't exists
```

Comment: Please show how you imported MessageError

Answer (score 0):

Your solution was very close. It looks like you were catching the wrong error.

Instead of catching for `MessageError`, you should catch for `SecretNotFoundError`.

```
from google.colab import userdata
try:
  userdata.get('mySecret')
except userdata.SecretNotFoundError:
  print("The mySecret doesn't exists")
```

This will print as expected.

```
The mySecret doesn't exists
```

If the secret exists **but** not granted access for this notebook, you would have to catch for `NotebookAccessError` instead.

---

If you do not care which error is caught, you can do like this:

```
from google.colab import userdata
try:
  userdata.get('mySecret')
except (userdata.SecretNotFoundError, userdata.NotebookAccessError):
  print("invalid mySecret")
```